# c++ Vector of threads - Compiler error

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, vector

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am learning multithreading.

I was trying to create a vector of threads by the input in the function.
When I just created a vector of threads everything was fine but when I tried to access the vector the cannot be compiled any more.

The error:

```
C2661 'std::tuple<void(__cdecl *)(int,int,std::ofstream&),
      int,int,std::basic_ofstream<char,std::char_traits<char> > >::tuple':
      no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
```

The code:

```
std::vector<std::thread> t(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    t[i] = std::thread(writePrimesToFile, begins[i], ends[i], file);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    t[i].join();
```

Threads function signature:

```
void writePrimesToFile(int begin, int end, ofstream& file)
```

By the way the function itself worked without threads.

Comment: Can you show `begins` definition?

Comment: And `ends`? And `file`? And preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please dont post links to images of text. Copy-paste the *complete* error output, *as text* into the body of the questions. Lastly please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Explain 'crashed in the compilation process'

Comment: begins and ends are just int[]. I've tried to use a thread from the vector without that for loop and it still crashed. And file is just a file. As I said the function "writePrimesToFile" did work in main

Comment: It is hard to tell where the problem is coming from due to lack of a verifiable example. I only know a little bit about threads, but from the error message from your graphic that should of been posted within the answer instead of a link, it appears you have a mismatch in parameters for one of your function calls.

Comment: And that your problem is not a program crash; it is a compilation error. The program can not even begin to run or execute because if failed to compile. A program only crashes after execution begins.

Comment: `std::vector<std::thread> t(N);` does not do what you think it does. You just default-constructed `N` objects of type `std::thread` which you do not need (and indeed throw away in the next loop). You probably meant `std::vector<std::thread> t; t.reserve(N);`.

Comment: try `std::ref(file)` - iostreams are not copyable. And it would not work as you expect. Looks like you read from file or position it, that will not work on shared `fstream`